# Issue in selecting the keyboard suggestion in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

In my signup page, i have selected the content type as 'Telephone Number' for the phone number textfield. It shows the SIM number only in very few iOS versions. For example, it doesn't show the phone number suggestion in iOS 11. it shows up in few version but i when i click on the suggestion it does not fill in the textfield. Can someone throw some light on it. What is the trick to make it show in all versions and how can i fill it in the textfield when i click on the suggestion?

[image]

Comment: It is just a suggestion based on what iOS has seen the user type in telephone number fields previously. There is no way to force it. I am not sure why tapping the suggestion doesn't insert it. Do you have any code in the text field delegate that would prevent the number from being entered.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and it turned out to be our `UITextFieldDelegate` `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method that tried to clean up the input itself and return `false`. That prevented this feature from working. When I changed that to return `true` (but asynchronously call the clean up routine), the pasting feature worked.